# Magento 2 Invoice Pdf footer paragraph cutting off - not going to next page

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

I am trying to add a couple of lines as my magento 2 store's pdf invoice's footer - technically trying to set it just after the Totals.

So I have overriden the file Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php in my custom module. To add the footer I have written the below function:

```
protected function _drawFooter(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {   

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(1, 1, 1));
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
            $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 10);

        $page->drawText('EFT Details: ', 35, $this->y -10, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('Account Name:  , 40, $this->y -25, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText('BSB: XXXXXXX Account No: XXXXXX' , 250, $this->y -25, 'UTF-8');

        $page->drawText('Please put your order number as reference' , 40, $this->y -35, 'UTF-8');

         $page->drawText('Return and Refund Policy: ', 35, $this->y -50, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('Products returned due to change of mind, not being suitable or if the job did not go forward, must be returned within' , 40, $this->y -65, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('30 days of the purchase. The amount paid will be applied as a store credit to your account. ' , 40, $this->y -75, 'UTF-8');
             $page->drawText('If a refund is required, the following fees will apply: ' , 40, $this->y -85, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('2% credit card process fee applicable for all orders paid with Visa or Master. ' , 50, $this->y -100, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('3% credit card process fee applicable for all orders paid with AMEX. ' , 50, $this->y -110, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('Shipping cost will be deducted from refund (i.e. shipping to customers and pick up cost).' , 50, $this->y -120, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText('Restocking fee may apply.' , 50, $this->y -130, 'UTF-8');

               $page->drawText('Warranty' , 35, $this->y -145, 'UTF-8');

                $page->drawText(' LED Products have either a 3 or 5 years full product replacement warranty.' , 40, $this->y -160, 'UTF-8');

                 $page->drawText(Lighting Products have 2 years full product replacement warranty.' , 40, $this->y -170, 'UTF-8');
             $page->drawText('For warranty claims regarding transit damage, the claim must be made within 5 . business days of receiving of goods.' , 40, $this->y -180, 'UTF-8');
             $page->drawText('The warranty service is limited to the replacement or repair of products that have become defective due to normal usage,' , 40, $this->y -190, 'UTF-8');


                $page->drawText('For Labour Warranty conditions please refer to our website.' , 40, $this->y -210, 'UTF-8');


        }

And then called this function below the within the getPdf function like this

 public function getPdf($invoices = [])
{
  ........
 ..........
 $this->_drawFooter($page); 
 $this->_afterGetPdf();
return $pdf;

}
```

it is generating output as following if there is only one or two items - as there are plenty of spaces on the page 
[image]

but if there are lots of products and the footer needs to move to the next page  then it gets cut off at the middle like this:

[image]

I am very new to magento and totally at loss..please help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution to the issue and posting this answer as someone else might find it useful.

I modified the _drawFooter function as following:

```
 protected function _drawFooter(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {   
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $this->insertLogo($page);
..................
```

all remaining codes were same.

This way the terms and conditions were going to a new page irrespective of how many orders were placed. Also the next page had the logo of the business. 
Hope this is helpful.